# How to list organizations that has not made a group with GroupCategoryID 36

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got a database with multiple tables, and I list all the organizations that has made a group with GroupCategoryID 36:

```
SELECT Sum(GroupStatistics.memberAttendants),
       Organizations.Name
FROM   [Main].[dbo].[Groups]
       INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].Organizations
               ON Groups.OrganizationID = Organizations.OrganizationID
       INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].GroupStatistics
               ON Groups.GroupID = GroupStatistics.GroupID
       INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].GroupCategories
               ON Groups.Category_GroupCategoryID = GroupCategories.GroupCategoryID
WHERE  Groups.Category_GroupCategoryID = 36
       AND ( GroupStatistics.memberAttendants IS NOT NULL
              OR GroupStatistics.memberAttendants > 0 )
       AND GroupStatistics.StatisticsDate LIKE '%.2014'
GROUP  BY Organizations.Name
```

Now I want to make a list that lists all those who has NOT established a group with GroupCategoryID 36.
Can anyone help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Just change the WHERE Clause: Groups.Category_GroupCategoryID <> 36

Comment: The Organizations makes other groups with other GroupCategoryID, so that won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(GroupStatistics.memberAttendants),Organizations.Name
FROM [Main].[dbo].[Groups]
INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].Organizations
ON Groups.OrganizationID = Organizations.OrganizationID
INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].GroupStatistics
ON Groups.GroupID = GroupStatistics.GroupID
INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].GroupCategories
ON Groups.Category_GroupCategoryID = GroupCategories.GroupCategoryID
WHERE Groups.OrganizationID NOT IN (
SELECT OrganizationID
FROM [Main].[dbo].[Groups]
INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].GroupStatistics
ON Groups.GroupID = GroupStatistics.GroupID
INNER JOIN [Main].[dbo].GroupCategories
ON Groups.Category_GroupCategoryID = GroupCategories.GroupCategoryID
WHERE Groups.Category_GroupCategoryID = 36 AND (GroupStatistics.memberAttendants IS NOT NULL 
OR GroupStatistics.memberAttendants > 0) AND GroupStatistics.StatisticsDate LIKE '%.2014')
GROUP BY Organizations.Name
```

You can use the **NOT IN** condition

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189062(v=sql.105).aspx